# Choose a function at run time using overloaded resolution in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, runtime, dynamic-cast

I have a method of a class (`bar` from `app` in the example below). I want with method to call automatically, I mean without conditional statement like `if`, overloaded functions (`create` in the example).
Which function to call cannot be known at compile time because it relies on hardware input (user input in the example).
In my example, base class `b` and derived classes `d1` and `d2` cannot be changed. In the context of the real code, they are basically part of the hardware driver.

```
#include <iostream>

class b
{
 virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class d1 : public b
{
 void foo() override {};
};

class d2 : public b
{
 void foo() override {};
};

class app
{
 int create(d1 & p1){return 1;}
 int create(d2 & p2){return 2;}
 public:
 app()
 {
 }
 void bar(b * p)
 {
  ::std::cout<<this->create(*p)<<::std::endl;
 }
};

int main()
{
 b * either1or2;

 auto input(0);
 ::std::cin>>input;
 if(input % 2 == 0)
 {
  either1or2 = new d1;
 }
 else
 {
  either1or2 = new d2;
 }
 
 app a;
 a.bar(either1or2);
 return 0;
}
```

What I wrote is wrong because it requires knowledge at compile time.

```
::std::cout<<this->create(*p)<<::std::endl;
```

It should be more something like

```
::std::cout<<this->create(*dynamic_cast< decltype(*p) * >(p))<<::std::endl;
```

But the same issue arises because decltype is evaluate at compile time.

Comment: Downcasting is something you rarely want to do. I don't think you can do what you want to do in this way.

Comment: I should be safe in this context because the downcasting would be deduced by the pointed value. But I agree that I'm not sure it's possible, that's why I'm asking ^^

Comment: Overload resolution is *always* done at compile time.  The best you can do at run time is choose between different statements to execute.